# Why classification_report and confusion_matrix_normalized are different?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

What is the difference between `classification_report` and `confusion matrix normalized`? Why in `classification_report` last class is not accurate, and in confusion matrix normalized is most accurate?

This is the screenshots:

[image: classification_report]

[image: confusion matrix normalized]

Comment: What are the confusion matrix based on? 
Is it a prediction vs label confusion matrix? If so, it seems that they are using different metrics

Comment: The confusion matrix is always based on the same Y data (with labels) also passed to the classification_report.

Comment: The diagonal of the normalized confusion matrix is the recall. We see that for each class, the values do not correspond to the classification report. Please check the inputs of the functions, otherwise show the code that generates the reports.